# Powershell - Search XML for Element with certain name and add them to another XML document

Tags: arrays, xml, powershell, copy

I am attempting to search an XML document for entries with a certain string in an attribute field. If that string is present I want to copy the entire element to another xml with the same structure.

So far I am able to locate the elements and save them to an array. I am having issues with the foreach saving each one to the XML.

Both XML File Structure:

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <ClassConfiguratorConfig
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">   
    <Section>
>     <SProperties>
>       <SProperty Name="C_ITEM1VALUE" Value="1" />
>       <SProperty Name="C_ITEM2VALUE" Value="5" />
>       <SProperty Name="C_ITEM3VALUE" Value="20" />
>       <SProperty Name="C_ITEM4VALUE" Value="100" />
>       <SProperty Name="C_ITEM1TYPE" Value="0" />
>       <SProperty Name="C_ITEM2TYPE" Value="0" />
>       <SProperty Name="C_ITEM3TYPE" Value="0" />
>       <SProperty Name="C_ITEM4TYPE" Value="0" />
>       <SProperty Name="START_RETURNIMMEDIATELY" Value="FALSE" />
>       <SProperty Name="SUPER_EXITTIMEOUT" Value="10" />
>     </SProperties>   
    </Section> 
  </ClassConfiguratorConfig>
```

Current Code to find all instances of SProperty where the Name attribute contains "C_ITEM" in SProperty1.xml. Then add all entries of that to the SProperty2.xml

```
[xml]$XML1 = Get-Content "C:\Temp\SProperty1.XML"
[xml]$XML2 = Get-Content "C:\Temp\SProperty2.XML"

$Node1 = $XML1.ClassConfiguratorConfig.Section.SProperties
$Node2 = $XML2.ClassConfiguratorConfig.Section.SProperties

$Nodes = $XML1.SelectNodes("//SProperties/*[@*[contains(.,'C_ITEM')]]")

foreach ($Node in $Nodes){
       $XML2.CreateElement('SProperty')
       $Child.SetAttribute('Name',"$Node.Name")
       $Child.SetAttribute('Value',"$Node.Value")
       $Node2.AppendChild($Child)
   }
```

When the for loop process for some reason I am getting below as an output:

```
Name                       Value
----                       -----
System.Xml.XmlElement.Name System.Xml.XmlElement.Value
System.Xml.XmlElement.Name System.Xml.XmlElement.Value
System.Xml.XmlElement.Name System.Xml.XmlElement.Value
System.Xml.XmlElement.Name System.Xml.XmlElement.Value
System.Xml.XmlElement.Name System.Xml.XmlElement.Value
System.Xml.XmlElement.Name System.Xml.XmlElement.Value
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Probably the question would be improved if you could show what you expect the output to be in this case? Like a section saying I want the output to look like this: EXAMPLE CODE OF EXPECTED OUTPUT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you dont have your value inside $() when you are using "" around the variable.

```
       $child = $XML2.CreateElement('SProperty')
       $Child.SetAttribute('Name',"$($Node.Name)")  
       $Child.SetAttribute('Value',"$($Node.Value)")
```

`('Name',"$Node.Name")` is not right if you are trying to get the value of Name from $Node. You are in essence setting the attribute Name to `"$Node" + ".Node"` and Value to `"$Node" + ".Value"`.

In order for powershell to know you are trying to access the Name or Value property of Node, you have to use a complete variable within "" and that is done by encapsulating the $variable and property name with @(). So, `"$($Node.Name)"` will work.

Usage should be like this, `('Name',"$($Node.Name)")`